# Increment value by one on each instance

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement

hi have been workin on this .i need to increment the value of i on ech instance of the condition.currently i have three.the code below

```
<?php  if( !empty($instance['link']) ): ?>
    <div class="caption lft slide-heading" data-x="580" data-y="30" data-speed="1800" data-start="1200" data-easing="easeOutExpo">
        <a href="<?php echo $instance['link']; ?>">
            <?php if( !empty($instance['title']) ): echo apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']); endif; ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- FOCUS HEADING -->
<?php endif;?>
```

i tried

```
<?php   $i=0;$i++; if( !empty($instance['link']) ):  ?>
    <div class="caption lft slide-heading" data-x="580" data-y="30" data-speed="1800" data-start="1200" data-easing="easeOutExpo">   
        <a href="<?php echo $instance['link']; ?>"> 
            <?php if( !empty($instance['title']) ): echo apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']); endif; ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- FOCUS HEADING -->
<?php  echo $i; endif; ?>
```

this results **1 1 1** . I would like to get it as **1 2 3**. where did i went wrong? please help

update

[image]

Comment: You're not showing how this is being looped, but my guess would be that you're resetting $i to zero with each iteration and then incrementing it. So, it will 1 everytime. Set $i to zero **before** the loop starts.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialise your counting variable before you start the loop.
As it is now you set $i to 0 and increment it to 1 in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php     
if( !empty($instance['link']) )
{
    for($i = 1; $i < 4; ++$i)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"caption lft slide-heading\" data-x=\"580\" 
               data-y=\"30\" data-speed=\"1800\" data-start=\"1200\" 
               data-easing=\"easeOutExpo\">";

        echo "<a href=\"" . $instance['link'] . "\">";

        if(!empty($instance['title']))
           echo apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);   
        echo "</a></div>";
        echo $i . ' ';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 0123 0123 0123 it is returning like this

Comment: Isn't that what u needed ? - If u miss the space character add it the echo with echo $i . ' ';

Comment: it is returning 3 times

Comment: Impossible if u use my code. there only 1 loop - It must be out of the example you show us. Code running here : http://www.tehplayground.com/#wRVPD728D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79535/discussion-between-falt4rm-and-melvin).